# Making your Visual Studio Windows Application automatically update using Clickonce

Tags: asp.net, clickonce, installshield

I am using Installshield to create setup of my window application. Now this setup is being used on over 100 systems. How i can provide version update notification to the systems?.

I looked into many articles and find out that **Clickonce** is the best way to use to provide Minor or Major updates to the already installed application.

**Problem:**

I am new for Clickonce, Please provide me any reference by which i can implement auto update feature in my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ASP desktop application?

Comment: I corrected it. So now are you able to provide me solution of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but these links should give you all the information you need to publish and implement the auto update feature in you application:

[How to publish a ClickOnce application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=vs.140).aspx)

[Choosing a ClickOnce Update Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx)

[How to manage Updates for a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb.aspx)

Comment: I will look into these and come back to you. Hope these references meet my requirements.